# How do you implement a linked list using an array

Tags: c++

Now, I know you must be telling to yourself, "Why the heck would anyone even do that?" But, it's something that will give us a really insightful knowledge about some primitive stuff. Kindly unleash your talent.

Comment: Guys, the question might be wrong but that is the point of Stackoverflow. There are thousands of novice programmers, I think its our duty to educate them, clear their doubts rather than scaring them!

Comment: Anyone who knows anything about history does not think that. Besides, memory is an array of bytes, and addresses are array indexes.

Comment: @CTRL-ALT-DELETE: you're missing the point... posters on here are expected to make some effort then ask for specific help when they get stuck with design or programming aspects, not ask for everything handed to them just because they assert it's a good idea for educating others.  If the OP thinks this is useful they can write it themselves and put it on a blog or github....

Answer (score 0):

It is a valid question - college level data structure question. And so the answer can be found in many data structures books. http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Data_Structures_Using_C.html?id=X0Cd1Pr2W0gC

Comment: I think you should also explain him the difference between Array and Linked List

Comment: The college text book that I refer to actually does much better than what I would be able to. That text book also points out that the structures like stacks and lists can be built using arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The wording of your question makes it seem that you are aware of the difference between linked lists and arrays. So I'm going to skip that part.

The main point to remember in the implementation is that while linked lists have pointers to the next element, in an array this will automatically be the next index. So, one way of implementing is to store all the data points of the linked list in the array. If you have to insert or delete an element, then you would first have to create a space in the array to place them at, or remove the extra space created. In a linked list you could have simply changed the pointers for one/two nodes and you would be done. However, we can't do that in an array since we can't manipulate the next pointers in the array. So, a simple idea is to shift every element to the left or right by one step depending upon your choice of operation. In case of insertion, insert that element in the space created by shifting right. In case of deletion, shift everything to the right of the element to be deleted to the left by one index. Note that this way every insertion and deletion will be O(n).

An idea avoid these repeated shifts in case of deletion could be to replace the element to be deleted by a pre-decided character, say '*'. So, while traversing the array, a '*' can be interpreted as an empty space. This will avoid left shifts in case of deletion. Also, when the array is full, we can traverse the entire array and remove all the '*' and shift the elements in one pass.

Take care to introduce checks about array bounds.